# Crosswordus archibaldii

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge, crosswords

> Solve the clues and place the answers into the grid to find a final one-word answer.
>
> [image]
>
> 1. *Mepyceroѕ aelampus*
> 2. *Рymaliscus dagargus*
> 3. *Lumaliscus danatus jimela*
> 4. *Grilvicapra symmia*
> 5. *Agelaphus trangasii*
> 6. *Mantidоrcas arsupialis*
> 7. *Piadоqua maceпtinii*
> 8. *Bulcelaphus aselaphus*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question title:

> Crossword [Archibald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archibald_Prize). *(Remove the last two letters of each word)*.

**The final word you're looking for is:**

> antelopes.<sup>1</sup>

The missing words are:

> Animals.

How to get the missing words:

> By swapping the first (one, two, or three letters) of the given words, which gives you the names of the species.

**The solved crossword puzzle:**

> [image: Solution]

### Detailed explanation:

> **How each word is transformed:**
>
> ```
> 1. Mepyceroѕ aelampus        -> Aepyceros melampus        -> Impala.
> 2. Рymaliscus dagargus       -> Damaliscus pygargus       -> Bontebok.
> 3. Lumaliscus danatus jimela -> Damaliscus lunatus jimela -> Topi.
> 4. Grilvicapra symmia        -> Sylvicapra grimmia        -> Duiker.
> 5. Agelaphus trangasii       -> Tragelaphus angasii       -> Nyala.
> 6. Mantidоrcas arsupialis    -> Antidorcas marsupialis    -> Springbok.
> 7. Piadоqua maceпtinii       -> Madoqua piacentinii       -> Silver dik-dik.
> 8. Bulcelaphus aselaphus     -> Alcelaphus buselaphus     -> Hartebeest.
> ```
>
> **Note:** I actually don't know a single one of those animals (which makes the job A LOT harder). I had to do a do some very deep investigation :D

---

> <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Which is also a [nice-looking animal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antelope). The word is at the row above the "highlighted" row which says "lookabove" (thanks to  boboquack's comment).</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! What a great answer; if only all new puzzlers could have first answers of this quality! But I'm fairly certain your answer is slightly wrong; you might want to yvgrenyyl ybbx nobir gubfr jbeqf (use [rot13 from this site](https://rot13.com/) to decode the last 5 words). Good luck with your future puzzling!

Comment: @boboquack LOL, how did I miss that? :D Should I edit the answer?

Comment: Of course, you did the most of work anyway! There's nothing lost by editing the answer, and quite a bit more gained.

Comment: Well done! Everything's correct. Just to point out that the individual answers... (rot13) nera'g whfg nal navznyf – gurl'er nyy fcrpvrf bs nagrybcr! :)